# Get dataframe in periods of 10 seconds and average values in that window of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, average

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this (after some pre-processing):

```
[       doctets     Real First Packet           Real End Packet          Duration
49         456   2013-02-04 15:47:04.590    2013-02-04 15:47:04.654           64
50         456   2013-02-04 15:53:17.338    2013-02-04 15:53:17.466          128
...        ...                     ...                     ...               ...
10816    47087   2013-02-15 16:41:54.807    2013-02-15 16:42:01.335          6528
10817      168   2013-02-15 16:42:28.770    2013-02-15 16:42:28.898          128
```

I need each of the rows of my dataframe to be a time between

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 4, 8, 00, 00) #Feb 4 2013 at 8 am
end_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 15, 17, 00, 00) #Feb 15 2013 at 5 pm
```

I want to have the average ratio doctects/duration in windows of 10 seconds, **even if there is no data for a given window.** My desired output should look like this:

```
[                  window                           doctects/duration         
  2013-02-04 8:00:00 - 2013-02-04 8:00:10                      0
  2013-02-04 8:00:11 - 2013-02-04 8:00:21                      0
  2013-02-04 8:00:21 - 2013-02-04 8:00:31                  7.123
         .                                                     .
         .                                                     .
         .                                                     .
         .                                                     .
  2013-02-15 16:59:51 - 2013-02-15 17:00:00                 6.987]
```

I tried first doing this:

```
   df.asfreq(freq='10S')
```

But I'm not sure what else to try. Please any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using [grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and apply you can achieve what you want.  I've synthesized data

```
import numpy as np

r = pd.date_range("2013-02-04 8:00:00", freq="S", periods=60)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Real First Packet":r, "Real End Packet":r.shift(5),"doctets":np.random.randint(168,47087,len(r)),
             "duration":np.random.randint(64,6528, len(r))})

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Real First Packet", freq="10S")).apply(
    lambda r: pd.Series({
        "window":r["Real First Packet"].min().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " - " + r["Real First Packet"].max().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        "doctets/duration":(r.doctets/r.duration).mean()})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### output

|  | window | doctets/duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013-02-04 08:00:00 - 2013-02-04 08:00:09 | 23.0205 |
| 1 | 2013-02-04 08:00:10 - 2013-02-04 08:00:19 | 47.8008 |
| 2 | 2013-02-04 08:00:20 - 2013-02-04 08:00:29 | 15.8908 |
| 3 | 2013-02-04 08:00:30 - 2013-02-04 08:00:39 | 14.7253 |
| 4 | 2013-02-04 08:00:40 - 2013-02-04 08:00:49 | 17.7554 |
| 5 | 2013-02-04 08:00:50 - 2013-02-04 08:00:59 | 24.8611 |